# How to check if a SD card is formatted as Phone storage or Portable storage?

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-sdcard, android-storage

I'm an Android newbie. I'm coding an app on Android 9 with a feature:

"Check if a SD card is formatted as Phone storage or Portable storage"

I tried to google it but I couldn't find any solution.
Could you please help me with a solution for Java?

Below image describes the two options which I want to detect:
[image]

Comment: Have a look at the return value of getExternalFilesDirs().  If there is an sd card inserted and used as portable storage the second item points to the card. If there is no card inserted there is only one item. If there is a card inserted and used as internal memory there is only one item returned.

Comment: But... Why do you want to give your app that feature?

Comment: I wanna show a notification to user to format sdcard when internal storage is full.
How can i use getExternalFilesDirs to check it? could you please explain more details?

Comment: As soon as a user inserts a micro sd card the OS will ask what should be done with it. So it makes no sense trying to implement such.